# How to calculate kinv from the given k value

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, openssl

I am implementing an ECDSA NIST test vectors verification application. The test vectors are taken from http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/#09.

One of the test vectors is given below:

```
P-192 SHA1

Msg = 608079423f12421de616b7493ebe551cf4d65b92   
d = e14f37b3d1374ff8b03f41b9b3fdd2f0ebccf275d660d7f3   
Qx = 07008ea40b08dbe76432096e80a2494c94982d2d5bcf98e6     
Qy = 76fab681d00b414ea636ba215de26d98c41bd7f2e4d65477   
k = cb0abc7043a10783684556fb12c4154d57bc31a289685f25  
R = 6994d962bdd0d793ffddf855ec5bf2f91a9698b46258a63e   
S = 02ba6465a234903744ab02bc8521405b73cf5fc00e1a9f41
```

I am trying to calculate $k_{inv}$ from given $k$ value and I am using curve *“NID_X9_62_prime192v1”*.

Can anyone tell me how to calculate $k_{inv}$?

Comment: Closely related to this [question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15026/555)

Answer (score 4):

Just compute the multiplicative inverse $k^{-1}$ of $k$ modulo the prime order $n$ of the base point $G$ (I used the typical notation for the domain parameters of the curve). This can efficiently be done using [extended Euclid](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and should be available in any reasonable big integer library (typically something like modinverse). Thats it.